# CloudFlare WAF Custom Rule Issue

Tags: block, cloudflare, rules

I am using the CloudFlare WAF Custom Rule:

(ip.geoip.country ne "US")

with action set to Block.

This works great on the first domain I set it up on but doesn't work on any other domain. All sites are Wordpress. I have cleared cache on CF and on the servers and browser, and using ProtonVPN I have tried various countries but do not get blocked (except the first site). What could be causing this?

[www.cremationsocietywa.com](http://www.cremationsocietywa.com) works
[www.affordablecasket.org](http://www.affordablecasket.org) doesn't work

they both have the same rule deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Right now we are using `ip.geoip.country` option, and it works perfectly fine. I don't think it could be a problem with the option itself.

I believe you can specify all needed domains, in the rule like this:

`(ip.geoip.country ne "US" and http.host in {"test" "test2" "test3"})`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `(ip.src.country ne "US")`?

https://developers.cloudflare.com/ruleset-engine/rules-language/fields/

> `ip.src.country`
>
> In the WAF, the `ip.geoip.country` field (which is still available) is equivalent to `ip.src.country`.
> `ip.geoip.country` is being deprecated and we do not recommend using it.